# What is the meaning of words inside a function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a question for functions and I have this code:

```
$.validator.addMethod("lettersonly", function (value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || /^[a-z\s]*$/i.test(value);
}, "Please enter letters only");
```

What is the meaning of `function (value, element)` in jquery? What is the example of value and element in layman terms?

Comment: take a look at [this article](https://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.addMethod/)

Comment: It's an anonymous function runs when you want to validate letter-only rule

Answer (score 0):

Here

> $.validator.addMethod()

is a function, in which first param is the string and second one is a function name which is to be called. You can also define the function as a second parameter like:

```
function (value, element){
....
}
```

here value, element are two parameters for this function.

Comment: you may also explain how the parameters assigned.

Answer (score 0):

It's an anonymous function, a function without a name. I this case, it is sent as a parameter to the addMethod method on the validator object.

So, if you want to find out what is happening to the anonymous function being sent, check the addMethod method

Answer (score 0):

```
$.validator.addMethod("lettersonly", function (value, element) {
   return this.optional(element) || /^[a-z\s]*$/i.test(value);
}, "Please enter letters only");
```

The addMethod function take 3 parameters. The 2nd parameter is anonymous function and it is passes as parameter.
addMethod function may look like this

```
function(first_param,second_param,third_param) {

  //Perform some auction and call function that is passes to it as parameter.

 // second_param is function and it take 2 params. So
 var value = ''; //Some value
 var element = ''; //Some element

 second_param(value, element);
}
```